# Magento 2 Module Events

Tags: module, event-observer

I'm new to magento module development and trying to write my own little module.
Unfortunately, I'm having trouble understanding how to connect events to a REST request.

What I want to achieve:

- Whenever a customer buys a product, a REST request should be executed.
- The SKU of the product should be supplied to the rest request.

```php
$post = [
    'sku' => $productSku
];

$ch = curl_init('https://api.example.com/path');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I am using the latest version of Magento 2 CE.

Thank you for your time.

Best Regards,
Piotr

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick run down of how you could achieve that:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/events-and-observers.html

1. add a event listener in the global scope. the event should probably be "checkout_submit_all_after"
2. In your PHP Observer you should use the class \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Adapter\Curl to execute the rest call

Comment: Thank you Philipp. Will try it out.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Philipp Sander answare, this doc is really good for the consumption of external API.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ext-best-practices/tutorials/create-integration-with-api.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your additional comment.